# Is it possible to render MSAA to RGBA32F texture in WebGL2?

Tags: webgl, webgl2, hdr, msaa

Firstly, I have msaa working good, like this(abstract):

```
    sceneFramebuffer = new MultisampleRenderbuffer({
        msaa: 8,
        internalFormat: "RGBA8"
    });

    blitFramebuffer = new Framebuffer({
        internalFormat: "RGBA8",
        format: "RGBA",
        type: "UNSIGNED_INT"
    });

   Draw scene with sceneFramebuffer;

   sceneFramebuffer.blit(blitFramebuffer);

   Draw blitFramebuffer on the screen quad;
```

Now, I want to render sceneFramebuffer to RGBA32F for HDR purpose, and when I try this configuration:

```
sceneFramebuffer = new MultisampleRenderbuffer({
    msaa: 8
    internalFormat: "RGBA32F"
});

blitFramebuffer = new Framebuffer({
    internalFormat: "RGBA32F",
    format: "RGBA",
    type: "FLOAT"
});
```

I get this:
GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBlitFramebufferCHROMIUM: src and dst formats differ for color

But, when I set **msaa: 0** for sceneFramebuffer it shows my scene but no msaa antialiasing ofcourse.

Is it possible somehow to combine multisampling and float output, which I'd use for hdr?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem to work for me

```js
function main() {
  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
  if (!gl) {
    return alert('need webgl2');
  }
  // without this we can't render to RGBA32F
  if (!gl.getExtension('EXT_color_buffer_float')) {
    return alert('need EXT_color_buffer_float');
  }
  // just guessing without this we can't downsample
  if (!gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float_linear')) {
    return alert('need OES_texture_float_linear');
  }
  
  const msFB = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, msFB);
  const msRB = gl.createRenderbuffer();
  gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, msRB);
  const samples = 4;
  const internalFormat = gl.RGBA32F;
  const width = 16;
  const height = 16;
  gl.renderbufferStorageMultisample(
     gl.RENDERBUFFER, samples, internalFormat, width, height);
  gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(
     gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.RENDERBUFFER, msRB);
  checkFramebuffer(gl);
  
  gl.clearColor(1,0,0,1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  const texFB = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, texFB);
  const tex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  const levels = 1;
  gl.texStorage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, levels, internalFormat, width, height);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(
      gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
  
  checkFramebuffer(gl);
  
  // check before
  checkPixel(gl, 'before blit')
  
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.READ_FRAMEBUFFER, msFB);
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, texFB);
  gl.blitFramebuffer(
     0, 0, width, height,
     0, 0, width, height,
     gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, gl.LINEAR);
     
  console.log('ERROR?:', glEnumToString(gl, gl.getError()));
  
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, texFB);
  checkPixel(gl, 'after blit:');
}

function checkFramebuffer(gl) {
  const status = gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER);
  if (status !== gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    console.error(glEnumToString(gl, status));
  }
}

function checkPixel(gl, msg) {
  const pixel = new Float32Array(4);
  gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, pixel);
  console.log(msg, Array.from(pixel).join(', '));
}
  
function glEnumToString(gl, v) {
  const hits = [];
  for (const key in gl) {
    if (gl[key] === v) {
      hits.push(key);
    }
  }
  return hits.length ? hits.join(' | ') : `0x${v.toString(16)}`;
}

main();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Just to make it clear it has nothing to do with texStorage2D

```js
function main() {
  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
  if (!gl) {
    return alert('need webgl2');
  }
  // without this we can't render to RGBA32F
  if (!gl.getExtension('EXT_color_buffer_float')) {
    return alert('need EXT_color_buffer_float');
  }
  // just guessing without this we can't downsample
  if (!gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float_linear')) {
    return alert('need OES_texture_float_linear');
  }
  
  const msFB = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, msFB);
  const msRB = gl.createRenderbuffer();
  gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, msRB);
  const samples = 4;
  const internalFormat = gl.RGBA32F;
  const width = 16;
  const height = 16;
  gl.renderbufferStorageMultisample(
     gl.RENDERBUFFER, samples, internalFormat, width, height);
  gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(
     gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.RENDERBUFFER, msRB);
  checkFramebuffer(gl);
  
  gl.clearColor(1,0,0,1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  const texFB = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, texFB);
  const tex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  const level = 0;
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat, width, height, 0,
                gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, null);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(
      gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
  
  checkFramebuffer(gl);
  
  // check before
  checkPixel(gl, 'before blit')
  
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.READ_FRAMEBUFFER, msFB);
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, texFB);
  gl.blitFramebuffer(
     0, 0, width, height,
     0, 0, width, height,
     gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, gl.LINEAR);
     
  console.log('ERROR?:', glEnumToString(gl, gl.getError()));
  
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, texFB);
  checkPixel(gl, 'after blit:');
}

function checkFramebuffer(gl) {
  const status = gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER);
  if (status !== gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    console.error(glEnumToString(gl, status));
  }
}

function checkPixel(gl, msg) {
  const pixel = new Float32Array(4);
  gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, pixel);
  console.log(msg, Array.from(pixel).join(', '));
}
  
function glEnumToString(gl, v) {
  const hits = [];
  for (const key in gl) {
    if (gl[key] === v) {
      hits.push(key);
    }
  }
  return hits.length ? hits.join(' | ') : `0x${v.toString(16)}`;
}

main();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: I see
I use 
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalFormat, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, null);
instead of  gl.texStorage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, levels, internalFormat, width, height);

I'll try to change it...

Comment: could you explain please, why I must use level = 1 in texStorage2D ?

Comment: You can use `texImage2D` as well (updated answer). `texStorage2D` takes the number of level**s** and allocates all of them. In this case we want 1 level(s)   Did you figure out what you were doing differently?

Comment: I am confused...it works too...even in my code...I suppose I made mistake when I created framebuffer texture with texImage2D, I lost RGBA32F and used RGBA instead. Eventually I'm happy that I can go further to hdr. Thanks Gman!